# Does Euclid's bisection of an angle fail for $\frac \pi 3$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Does Euclid's bisection of an angle fail for angles of $\frac \pi 3$ (that is, of equilateral triangles)?

In [Book I Prop. 9](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI9.html) Euclid shows how to bisect an angle by constructing an equilateral triangle across it, and then connecting the angle's vertex to a point on the triangle.  A [modern version](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bisection_of_Angle) of this is given on [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bisection_of_Angle).  But these constructions seem to assume the point on the equilateral triangle will be distinct from the vertex of the angle, which is *not* necessarily true if the angle is $\frac \pi 3$.

Of course, the repair to the construction is easy: just construct the equilateral triangle on the *other* side of the line.  But the fact that such a triangle exists is never shown by Euclid (I.1) or by the [modernized proofs on ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Construction_of_Equilateral_Triangle).

### Updates

*To address the comments:*

[image]

In the diagram, we wish to bisect angle $BAC$, and we do so by constructing an equilateral triangle $FED$.  The problem is that if the angle is $\frac \pi 3$, we may get point $F$ *is* point $A$. The construction only works when $F$ is *distinct* from $A$.

It is well known that there are many omissions in *Elements*.  However, to my knowledge, these are always cases where Euclid assumes something without (explicitly) proving it; but, in each case, the fact is indeed provable (at least with a sufficient set of axioms).  This case is different, because it is indeed quite possible for $A = F$, in which case a different construction is needed.  Are there any other known cases where *Elements* does something like that?

Comment: I don't see how it fails for $\pi/3.$ You bisect the opposite side of the triangle, and that is always not one of the vertices, unless the angle is $\pi$ or $0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Updated with a diagram showing how the construction may fail

Comment: The construction is to draw circles around $C$ with radius $CD$ and visa versa. This gives two points of intersection, not one $F.$ So you pick an $F$ which is not $A.$

Comment: In the Euclid translation cited, the instruction is to construct "*the* equilateral [...] on $DE$", not "*an* ...". If the translation is accurate on this subtlety (and arguably even if it isn't), then Euclid would seem to be implicitly qualifying which of the two available equilateral triangles to use; namely, *the one whose apex is separated from $A$ by line $DE$*, or perhaps *any one whose apex isn't $A$*. (Either way, we may need to make allowances for Euclid's omissions regarding plane separation and/or the existence of two distinct points of intersection for the construction's circles.)

Comment: Euclid supposed his reader was clever enough to pick the right triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following proof is accessible via Euclid's axioms.

Claim: Let two circles centered at points $P$ and $Q$ intersect at a point A lying off $\overline{PQ}$. Then the circles also intersect at a point $B$ distinct from $A$.

Proof: Construct the perpendicular to $\overline{PQ}$ through $A$ which intersects $\overline{PQ}$ at $M$. Extend $\overline {AM}$ past $M$ to point $B$ such that $\overline{MB}$ is congruent with $\overline{MA}$. Then $\triangle PMA$ is congruent with $\triangle PMB$ via SAS, so corresponding sides $\overline{PA}$ and $\overline{PB}$ are also congruent proving that $B$ lies on $\bigcirc P$. Similarly $\triangle QMA$ is congruent with $\triangle QMB$ leading to $B$ lying on $\bigcirc Q$.

If this proof is valid, it implies that we can choose either of two points of intersection when we construct the arcs, and at least one is perforce distinct from the vertex of the angle.

Comment: I think this is _probably_ OK, My reservation is the phrase "opposite side of $\bar{PQ}$ from $A$". Is that pure Euclid?

Comment: @EthanBolker We can eliminate the reference to "opposite side" by rewording this as: Extend $AM$ (I.Post.2) and then cut it off at $B$ so that $MB = AM$ (I.3).

Answer (score 5):

One of the known defects in Euclid's axiom system is the missing discussion of "betweenness". That's important for triples of points on a line. In this case the issue is the analogous one of "sidedness" that can distinguish between sides of a line.

See
[Hilbert’s Axioms for Euclidean Plane Geometry](https://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Edroyster/courses/fall11/ma341/axioms/Hilbert.htm)

and
https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/Geometry/notes-Wylie/Geometry-Wylie-2-2.pdf

Comment: I accept that betweenness is omitted from _Elements_, but in each case I'm aware of, it's of the form "Euclid assumes, but does not prove, this fact, which is indeed provable if we enrich our axiom system to include betweenness".  That's very different than assuming a fact that is not always true even under the enriched axiom system.  Are there other cases of this?

Comment: I don't think Euclid is assuming something not always true. What he is assuming is that there is at least one point on the potential bisector different from the vertex. That can be proved with patched axioms. (I don't know of "other cases" of the kind you seek.)

Comment: Robert, to add betweenness to the axioms, we have to add more than just the word, we have to add additional axioms about betweenness. In particular, Euclid does not let you prove that, for any distinct points $A,B,C$ on a line, there is one point between the other too. The word "between" doesn't magically solve the problem for Euclid, you have to add axioms of betweenness.